# Connecting to Firebird on Linux from a CGI application under Apache gives permissions error

Tags: linux, apache, cgi, freepascal, firebird2.1

I'm writing a small program in Free Pascal on Linux and connecting to a Firebird database on the same server. For testing, I initially wrote a console application using the TIBConnection components in FP and successfully connected to the Firebird database and listed records from one of the tables.

Now I'm wanting to do the same thing from a CGI application under Apache. A sample CGI app with various parameters displays different HTML results via the WebBroker "actions" like expected.

So both preliminary tests, connecting to Firebird and getting a CGI web app running, have worked.  The final test is to combine them and that's where my problem is.

Whenever I run the test cgi application and try to connect to the Firebird database, I get a "permission denied" error. I've left the username, password, and port all at defaults, have checked the firewall, switched between "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" and several other things including setting the permissions on the database file to read/write globally (for temporary testing, of course).

I've found lots of information on the internet about connecting to Firebird on Linux and lots of information about writing CGI applications, but very little where it combines the two subjects.  I'm sure there's a subtle yet important security or firewall issue, but it eludes me.

- CentOS 6.6 64-bit on a virtual machine
- Firebird 2.1.7 64-bit
- Lazarus 1.4.0 64-bit

Anyone have any suggestions on what I could try?

Comment: With your console program, are you also connecting through the server? Firebird also has a local mode connecting to the databasefile with your user, not through the database server (and its user). Maybe the database file is not accessible to the Firebird server user (eg the user has no rights to the file), while your own user does have access.

Comment: I'm not using FB embedded so believe the console program connects through the server. I set the group of the database file to be apache, the user the CGI app is running under, so it should have rights to that file.

Comment: Local connection != embedded (although it it's almost identical). However if you are connecting through the Firebird server, then not apache needs to have access to the database files, but the user running the Firebird server (usually firebird) needs to have rights to the database files.

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by local mode. Yes, Firebird has permissions to the database file--it's owned by the firebird user. I can access the same database on the same machine with an application that is not running under Apache.

Comment: Could you post the code you use to connect?

Comment: I'm using Lazarus and the TIBConnection components and call `InitializeIBase60(fblib21)` to force it to use the 2.1 library instead of the default 2.5 library, then simply call the component's `Open` method. I've tried a variety of combinations of property values such as filling in the HostName with an IP Address or leaving it blank or even adding the port number. The username/password are default for Firebird databases and I've also tried explicitly specifying the path or just using an alias to the database file. Remember, this same code works perfectly from a stand-alone Linux application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get it working by reading the solution to a [different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867286/apache-httpd-var-www-html-cgi-scripts-throw-500-internal-server-error). Not sure why disabling the firewall didn't work (I had to completely uninstall it) and don't know what SELinux is yet (had to set it to "permissive"), but I will need to study those two issues so the live server won't be left vulnerable.